# Self studying higher mathematics?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, soft-question

I'm fairly well-versed in calculus but I would like to explore beyond calculus. I have looked into the basics of some topics in higher mathematics such as group theory and abstract algebra and they intrigue me. I am wondering if there are any recommended methods or resources I should use to learn more about these topics. And is there any recommended starting point?

Comment: I would recommend starting with linear algebra, if you have not taken it. At the risk of flagrant self-promotion, I'll suggest that you take a look [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/896575/what-sequence-should-i-study-these-topics-in/896741#896741) related thread to get some more ideas about "where to begin."

Answer (score 2):

These free video lectures by B. Gross at Harvard are outstanding:

http://www.extension.harvard.edu/open-learning-initiative/abstract-algebra

They even have a set of notes taken by a very capable grad student.

Answer (score 0):

Check out saylor.org. It's a free website with a pretty full curriculum of undergraduate math courses and each course has readings, videos, problem sets, etc. Really everything you need to self-study if you don't have the desire or opportunity to enroll in an actual course. Good luck!